# How to increase Maven memory in Windows using command prompt

Tags: java, maven

Whenever I run mvn install,my machine never completes it. I just want to increase the maven memory using command prompt.

Comment: “Never completes”? Hangs or gives an error message?

Comment: No error message or hangs but looks like it runs in type of infinite loop

Comment: You can either attach VisualVM to see what it is doing, or run `mvnDebug` instead, attach a debugger, and start Maven to be able to see what it is doing when it takes a very long time.  This is like any other large program that behaves strange.